# Iframe content displaying in Chrome, but missing in FireFox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, extjs5

'testBox' is id of a Iframe which is creating in Extjs.
Now I want to add a div in document of Iframe.
These lines are working in chrome but not working in firefox

```
testBoxdoc = Ext.getCmp('testBox').el.dom.contentDocument;
var addTag="<div id=`t`/>";
$(testBoxdoc.body).append(addTag);
```

any body ..help ??

Comment: Whats the console say for error? F12 then "console" tab

Comment: Hello zer00ne
First of all thanks to reply..  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32437127/firefox-rendering-issue-in-ext-js
please refer this link  and give your help

Comment: I have an answer at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32437127/firefox-rendering-issue-in-ext-js